# With the x86 chips, are there any INT instructions other than with 0x80?

Tags: x86, int, intel, system-calls

I know Linux provide `int 0x80` for trapping into a system call but are there any others and what are their uses?

Comment: For starers, on which platform? And what does this have to do with C#, C++, C, or gcc?

Answer (score 5):

That's a pretty broad question but yes, the x86 chip allows a wide variety of software interrupts.

Linux uses `int 0x80` for its system call mechanism but you should be aware that later versions of the kernel can use `SYSENTER` rather than `int 0x80` since it's more efficient in some cases.

In real mode, the interrupt vector table was located at a specific place in memory. If you want details on the sort of things you could do, google for "Ralf Brown", he maintains the near-legendary "Interrupt List".

For protected mode, it can be found using a special processor register IDTR (IDT is the Interrupt Descriptor Table).

In both cases, you have 256 interrupts at your disposal.